# PHP: How To Create A List Of IP Addresses

Tags: php

I have a list of IP address ranges and I want to create a sequential list of all the IP addresses that the list of ranges contains.

The list is similar to below (but much longer)...

```
From IP To IP   Total IPs   Assign Date Owner
1.0.32.0    1.0.63.255  8192    12/4/2011   
1.1.16.0    1.1.31.255  4096    12/4/2011   
1.1.32.0    1.1.63.255  8192    12/4/2011   
1.2.16.0    1.2.31.255  4096    12/4/2011   
1.2.32.0    1.2.63.255  8192    12/4/2011   
1.2.64.0    1.2.127.255 16384   12/4/2011   
1.3.0.0 1.3.255.255 65536   12/4/2011
```

Currently, I'm repeating the same `for ()` loop.

```
<?php
for ($a = 0; $a <= 255; $a++) {
    echo "1.0.32.$a<br>";
}
for ($a = 0; $a <= 255; $a++) {
    echo "1.0.33.$a<br>";
}
for ($a = 0; $a <= 255; $a++) {
    echo "1.0.34.$a<br>";
}
for ($a = 0; $a <= 255; $a++) {
    echo "1.0.35.$a<br>";
}
for ($a = 0; $a <= 255; $a++) {
    echo "1.0.36.$a<br>";
}
for ($a = 0; $a <= 255; $a++) {
    echo "1.0.37.$a<br>";
}
?>
```

It spits out a list of IPs, as desired.

```
1.0.32.0
1.0.32.1
1.0.32.2
1.0.32.3
1.0.32.4
1.0.32.5
1.0.32.6
1.0.32.7
1.0.32.8
```

This will take me forever, doing it this way.  Hehehe...

I'm sure there is some fancy, mathematical, function that would clean that up.  I haven't figured it out, though.

Comment: you can make a for loop inside another for loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[PHP Generate IP Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168407/php-generate-ip-ranges)

> function ip_range($start, $end) {
>    $start = ip2long($start);
>    $end = ip2long($end);
>    return array_map('long2ip', range($start, $end) );
>   }
>   $range_one = "1.1.1.1";
>   $range_two = "1.1.99.255";
>   print_r(ip_range($range_one, $range_two) );

Edit: I created 65794 IP addresses in 1 second.

Comment: I had no idea about `ip2long`.  I'll look into it, more.

Comment: I created a variant of this code (http://pastebin.com/EWahenDy) and you can see the results (http://flcbranson.org/chineseips.php).  But, it isn't displaying all the results.  The page loads a lot of blank space, at the bottom, and it doesn't finish displaying the array.  Do you think I'm hitting a PHP wall or a server wall?

Comment: Apparently, it was an Internet Explorer wall.  Firefox displays it, just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, Firefox peters out not much later than IE.  I can't seem to display my entire results in any browser.

Comment: It is, consistently, breaking when I add one line of IP range.  The preceding ranges contain just under 500000 records.  Adding one more range takes it over 500000.  I wonder if that is a PHP array limit.  My whole list is over 300,000,000 addresses.

Comment: You are working with very very big data. You should part this.

Comment: Yeah, I found that I was running out of memory (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925885/array-size-limit-in-php).  `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` allowed more of the script to run.  Unfortunately, the whole script would take over an hour to process.  I don't think it would work, regardless of how high I set the memory.