# How Can I get Full IP Range of an IP List in PHP

Tags: php, ip-address

I have some it's in a text file ips.txt. I want to get the full IP range of each IP from that list.

```
   The following is included in ips.txt
    37.123.206.198
    115.84.182.49
    154.16.116.35
    115.84.182.49
    142.250.192.14
    112.78.2.75
```

How can I get the full IP range of each ip? 1-255

```
Example (with first IP)
37.123.206.198

37.123.1.1
37.123.2.1
37.123.3.1
37.123.4.1
.
.
.
37.123.255.1
37.123.1.2
37.123.2.2
37.123.3.2
37.123.4.2
```

Comment: Those are individual IP addresses.  They don't have a range.  What are you trying to accomplish with this list?

Comment: I've now explained it more clearly, please have a look.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How does a single IP address relate to the range you are looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting list IPs from CIDR notation in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931721/getting-list-ips-from-cidr-notation-in-php)

Comment: How many IPs in the file are you handling? 

Easiest way: Use `explode()` function to explode " . " and separate each number then manually traverse to each of them after that combine them all together. 

But consider using  `ip2long()` if you're handling with a large data.

Answer (score 0):

Read file and store ips in an array. Then:

```
<?php
$ips = [
    "37.123.206.198",
    "115.84.182.49",
    "154.16.116.35",
    "115.84.182.49",
    "142.250.192.14",
    "112.78.2.75"
];

$result = [];

foreach ($ips as $ip) {
    $ip_arr = explode('.', $ip);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 255; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j <= 255; $j++) {
            $new_ip = $ip_arr[0] . '.' . $ip_arr[1] . '.' . $i . '.' . $j;
            $result[$ip][] .= $new_ip;
        }
    }
}

print_r($result["37.123.206.198"][0]);


?>
```

Output: `37.123.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [ip2long](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) to convert the IP addresses into integers.

```
/* Generate a list of all IP addresses between $start and $end (inclusive). */
function ip_range($start, $end) {
  return array_map('long2ip', range(ip2long($start), ip2long($end)) );
}
$ip_range = ip_range("1.1.1.1", "1.1.255.255");
foreach ($ip_range as $ip){
  echo $ip."<br>";
}
```

Try to run the code above and see if that's what you want.

**Note**: This will include x.x.x.0 as well (Ex: 1.1.2.0)

**References**: Check these out [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950801/php-how-to-create-a-list-of-ip-addresses/31950902#31950902), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168407/php-generate-ip-ranges).